# String set to null

Tags: c#, wpf, string, null

I have two Windows namely MainWindows and Form2 . On pressing a Button on MainWindows, Form2 appears . In the second Window I have two textboxes and I added strings to store whatever is in these textboxes when I click the Button of Form2 but they set to null instead of storing the values.

```
private void remove_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)          
 {           
    string userValue;

    userValue = user_Text.Text;
    form2 form = new form2();
    form.Show();
    form.Replace_Button.Click += Replace_Button_Click;

  }

  void Replace_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    form2 form = new form2();
    replaceFirstValue = form.firstValue_TextBox.Text;
    replaceLastValue = form.lastValue_TextBox.Text;
    repFirstConversion = int.TryParse(replaceFirstValue, out repFirstInt);
    repLastConversion = int.TryParse(replaceLastValue, out repLastInt);
    if (repFirstConversion == false)
         this.Close();
              //MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Integer");                       
    }
```

I don't have any code in form2.xaml.cs .

Comment: Just a tiny note about your code: It's usually more readable if you write `if (!repFirstConversion)` instead of `if (repFirstConversion == false)`.

Comment: @haindl , thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a new instance of `form2` in both event handlers, therefore you have two different forms. The latter knows nothing about the former and will only have default values.

You have to only create one instance of `form2` and store a reference to it in a member variable and then use that to retrieve the values.

```
private form2 form; // A member variable to hold a reference to the form

private void remove_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    form = new form2(); // Set the member variable
}
```

And from `Replace_Button_Click` remove the first line where you created a new instance of `form2`.

Comment: I understood your first two lines but I have no idea how to do that what you said in the last two lines because I am very new to C# and don't have much idea about it .

Comment: @ArsalanKhattak I added an example. Basically move the variable out of the method into the class so its value will stay. Then you create the form once and use the same form in the other button handler also.

Comment: The topic to research is called "scope". This should teach you what you need to know. In this case the form is local scope when it needs to be global.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me .